# How to create a null row on 2nd datagriview with using 1st datagridview cellclick event C#?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

When click on row working on it will create a blank row with only **"id"** other columns will be fill on another forms datagridview and when I click first datagridviews row has same id it will open second datagridview and show the same row.